# View Databricks notebooks outside Databricks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks

I have and exported dbc file with all my notebooks. Is it possible to open/convert them to be opened in jupyter notebook or some other IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Databricks natively stores it’s notebook files by default as DBC files, a closed, binary format. A .dbc file has a nice benefit of being self-contained. One dbc file can consist of an entire folder of notebooks and supporting files. But other than that, dbc files are frankly obnoxious.

However, there is a workaround using Databricks -CLI 
Install the Databricks CLI on your local computer as per [Databricks legacy CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html#set-up-the-cli)

[Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/databricks-cli.html)

```
pip install databricks-cli
databricks configure --token
```

and run the following to import the .py notebooks into your local folder

```
mkdir export_notebooks
cd export_notebooks
databricks workspace export_dir /Shared ./
```

Comment: has this worked ?

Answer (score 0):

I publish a tool to unpack .dbc archive files into their corresponding python and markdown files at https://github.com/activescott/dbcexplode

It doesn't require you to have a databricks workspace or account you can run it all locally.

Just download the python file from there and run it like

```
$ ./dbcexplode.py mynotebooks.dbc
```